# Intercept and override body with OHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I intercept a request and I override the body response, this works but I have a problem with `ResponseBody.create`, the final **body** is

> [text={"field1":"value1"}"}]

And I need that the body be:

> {"field1":"value1"}"}

I do not understand Why my body have "**[test=**" at the beginning.

This is my interceptor (contentType is "*application/json;charset=UTF-8*"):

```
public class MockInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        //I want to intercept the url "/user/locations"
        final Request request = chain.request();
        final Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        if (response.request().toString().indexOf("/user/locations") > 0) {
            final Response newResponse = new Response.Builder()
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), "{\"field1\":\"value1\"}"))
                    .code(200)
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                    .request(response.request())
                    .message("Intercepted!")
                    .build();

            return newResponse;
        } else {
            return response;
        }
     }
```

Any idea?.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that shows the response returned with the prefix?

Comment: @YuriSchimke I see the prefix when I inspect the object **newResponse**. I am using retrofit with DTOs, so when I call the service and I inspect the callback, my dto has each field with null. I suposse that retrofit can not mapping correctly the json with the prefix to the dto, maybe I am using a wrong way for create my own response.